# Makefile for minimizing steps when changing files

Tags: c++, c, shell, makefile, command-line

So here is the problem given:
[Link to picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c3Aw.png)

I have my makefile down below and it works, but the problem is its not the solution that they are looking for. I get the error message "Your makefile does too much work when only mainProg.cpp has been changed:".

When the mainProg.cpp is changed, it recompiles everything instead of just recompiling mainProg.cpp. I'm thinking it could be because everytime I call make, it has to recreate the cookie.h and cookie.cpp files from chomp.adt again and since it changes, make has to recompile it. The tricky part is, is that cookie.h and cookie.cpp has to be created through the makefile according to the directions. And as far as I know, there is no way to only create cookie.h and cookie.cpp the first time make is invoked. I don't understand how to solve this problem without having to recompile cookie.h and cookie.cpp each time. Just to quote the directions: "Your makefile should result in only the minimum required amount of steps when any input file to this process is changed." so I am not getting the minimum steps basically. Maybe I am understanding the problem wrong, any suggestions?

my makefile:

```
# Macro definitions for "standard" language compilations
# 
#  First, define special compilation flags. These may change when
#  we're done testing and debugging.
CPPFLAGS=-g -DDEBUG
# 
#  The following is "boilerplate" to set up the standard compilation
#  commands:
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .cpp .c .cpp .h .o
.c.o: ; gcc $(CPPFLAGS) -c $*.c
.cpp.o: ; g++ $(CPPFLAGS) -c $*.cpp
# 
# Targets:
# 
all: createfile mainProg.o cookie.o
        g++ -g mainProg.o cookie.o
        mv a.out playChomp

mainProg.o: mainProg.cpp

cookie.o: createfile cookie.cpp cookie.h

createfile:
        csplit chomp.adt "/Split Here/"
        mv xx00 cookie.h
        mv xx01 cookie.cpp

clean: 
        rm *.o cookie.h cookie.cpp playChomp
```

Answer (score 0):

When you touch `mainProg.cpp`, it must be recompiled.  Then the recipe for `createfile` doesn't create a file `createfile`, so it is always out of date, so the rules create `cookie.h` and `cookie.cpp` again, so `cookie.o` must be recompiled.  Hence, everything must be recompiled.

You probably need:

```
createfile: chomp.adt
        csplit chomp.adt "/Split Here/"
        mv xx00 cookie.h
        mv xx01 cookie.cpp
        touch createfile
```

Comment: So I did what you listed but then I get an error: "fatal error: cookie.h: No such file or directory". So basically the files cookie.cpp and cookie.h don't exist until the make command executes. This is the problem I'm struggling with is how to create cookie.cpp and cookie.h in a make command while not having to recompile if they don't change.

Comment: I'm out at the moment, but … get rid of createfile and make the source and header depend on `chomp.adt`.  That accurately defines the relationship.